# grails 3.3.9, plugin wont compile after adding the settings.gradle

Tags: grails

I have grails 3.3.9 installed on Mac.

If I create a normal application, e.g. using:

```
grails create-app myapp
```

I can create domain classes, views etc, run the app and see the web pages.

However, I need two different web apps (one for the internal backoffice, and one for the customer facing public website).  The solution is to create a core plugin which contains only the domain objects and service layer which is then called by the two web apps, and later API apps etc. also.

I followed the official instructions [here](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/plugins.html)

i.e.:

```
$ grails create-plugin core --profile=plugin --features=hibernate5,events
$ Grails create-app myapp
$ create settings.gradle with: include "myapp","core"
$ edit build.grandle of myapp and add:

grails {
    plugins {
        compile project(':core')
    }
}
```

Now when I try to compile either, or run any grails command (such as grails create-service) I get this:

```
| Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/Users/me/dev/grails_projects/tst/core/build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':core'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.grails.grails-plugin']
   > Could not find method runtimeOnly() for arguments [io.methvin:directory-watcher] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

If I remove the settings.gradle, I can compile the plugin.  If I add it back, compile (or any grails command such as create-domain-class) fails with the above error.

Here is the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "core"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-plugin"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-plugin-publish"
```

The offending line 17 is:

```
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-plugin"
```

I also tried creating the plugin with the name "corex" instead of core just in case that was a reserved word. Got same results - plugin wont compile.

Note, the project directory structure looks like this:

```
settings.gradle
myapp
   build.gradle
   etc.
core
   build.gradle.
   etc.
```

I also tried several variations of the line in settings.gradle, including:

1. include 'myapp', 'core'
2. include 'core', 'myapp'
3. include ":myapp", ":core"

Any ideas?

## UPDATE 1

I just tried this with 3.3.8 and it seems to work.  So it would appear to be a bug in 3.3.9 which prevents using modular apps.

Comment: Sounds like you don't really need your `core` to be a grails plugin, but rather a plain groovy project to depend on.

Comment: @injecteer, are you suggesting giving up on plugins (because they seem to be broken), and making a dependency to a full blown grails app instead of a plugin? Unfortunately, there are no profiles for an app which has no web (i.e. only provides service layer/domain objects).

Comment: no, I suggest you create a no-grails (as a whole) module project, which would contain your domain classes and service-like classes

Comment: I assume this is yours?  https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11221

Comment: I can confirm that this happens to me as well with a plugin. Grails 3.3.8 works, but Grails 3.3.9 complains about the directory-watcher dependency. It may be true for apps as well. I think this may be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first Google link by "Could not find method grailsPublish() for arguments" request I'll post the answer for this related issue here.

With Grails `4.0.12` when you've just created a plugin you won't be able to use Gradle commands like `./gradlew run-app`. It will fail with the mentioned error message ^.

And the reason is because Grails team broke the publishing plugin: https://giters.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12007

So to make your newly created project work you need to open `build.gradle` and comment/remove `grailsPublish {` section:
[image]